# Matching DB records within a certain tolerance for error

Tags: database, oracle

I have a reference table (REF), and a table of incomplete data (ICD).  Both record structures are the same.  In this case it happens to contain person related data.  I am trying to fill in records in ICD with data from the best matching row in REF, if a best matching row exists within reason.  The ICD table may have or be missing first name, middle name, last name, address, city, state, zip, dob, and some others.

I need to ensure that the data I fill in is 100% accurate, so I already know I will not be able to fill it in on ICD rows where there isn't a reasonable match.

To this point I have written close to a dozen variations of matching queries, running over currently unmatched rows, and bringing over data in the case of a match.  I know there must be a better way.

What I would like to do is to set up a weight on certain criteria, and then take the summed weight for all satisfied criteria, and if above a certain threshold, honor the match.  For example:

- first name match = 15 points
- first name soundex match = 7 points
- last name match = 25 points
- last name soundex match = 10 points
- middle name match = 5 points
- address match = 25 points
- dob match = 15 points

Then I search for previously unmatched rows, and any match above a sum of 72 points is declared a confident match.

I can't seem to get my head around how to do this in a single query.  I also have a unique id in each table (they don't align or overlap, but it may prove useful in keeping track of a subquery result).

Thanks!!!

Comment: forget about doing this in a single query.  What you're attempting to do is build a matching system, which in most cases I've seen have some complex logic (fuzzy matching using lucene/solr or maybe Oracle Text).  Depending on your skill set, you'd be better off working on the framework of the system (pl/sql perhaps), because it will grow more complex as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @tbone was the most correct, but I cannot mark it as an answer because it was just a comment.

I did in fact create a package to deal with this, which contains two functions.

The first function queries any record from the reference table that matches any of a variety of indexes.  It then calculates a score associated with each field.  For example, last name exact match is worth 25, last name soundex match is worth 16, null is worth 0 and a total mismatch is worth -15.  These are summed together, and then I ran various queries to tell how low the threshold could be before letting in junk.  The first function returned each row from ref, and the score associated with it, in desc order.

The second function uses lead and lag to specifically consider the highest score returned by the first function, and then I added a second check, that the highest score was at least a reasonable number of points in the lead from the second highest score.  This trick eliminated my false matches.  The second function returns a single unique id of the match if there is a match.

From there is was pretty easy to write an update statement on the ICD table.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic ideas:

If there is no column which is guaranteed to match you will have to consider every row in REF for every row in ICD. Basically this is just a join of the two tables without any join condition.

This join gives you pairs of rows, i.e. twice the number of columns in each table. Now you'll have to apply your ranking system and compute an additional column `weight`. You can do this with a stored procedure or lots of decodes, something like

```
decode(REF.firstName, ICD.firstName, 15, 0) + decode ...
```

Now you select the ones which have a weight greater than 72. The problem is that one ICD row may have more than one confident match. If you want the best match only, then you better order your result by weight descending and perform your updates. If an ICD row has more than one confident REF row, you will do some obsolete updates, but the better update will always come last and overwrite previous updates.

If you want to do it all in a single update is yet another challenge.